# Is there any terminal tool where you can zoom in and out the screen?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, display, display-settings, display-manager

So I know there's zooming tool in universal access menu in Ubuntu, but currently I can't find how to operate it through command line, plus it can't zoom out.

My second attempt is use `xrandr --output Virtual1 --panning 3840x2160 --mode 1920x1080` but it has restrictions which currently I can only zoom in two times or four times, in another word predefined resolution.

So I'm looking for any zooming tool that allows me to both zoom in and zoom out the how viewport through terminal (not something like changing terminal font). Is there any tools like this available out there?

Comment: until you use xrandr I guess you use a Xterminal so try ctlr+mousewheel

Comment: @francoisP No I mean what command can I run on terminal to zoom in and out the whole screen (something like the universal access does)

Comment: You can't "zoom in and out the whole screen". The hardware just doesn't display the framebuffer this way. For smooth zooming, you need something that copies an existing screen (just like the zooming tool does).

Comment: @dirkt then is there any zooming tool that can be operate through terminal?

Comment: I don't know any zooming tool with command line options, or terminal interaction. But the tools are all open source, so of course you can modify them. And of course you can use the usual X automation to send mouse or keyboard events to the zooming tool from the command line. But that's not the main problem, the main problem is that you need to copy a zoomed version of an existing framebuffer to a window in another framebuffer to be able to use a zooming tool. This is slow, and not easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

On Gnome will screen zoom (you many need to enable in acc3e:
Super +
Super -

[image]